# relaying redis subscription messages to websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, publish-subscribe

subscribing to redis with a pattern `(*:*:*)` which recieves data every minute; also operating as a websocket server which checks for a particular subscription message, and if the data for the particular subscription message is returned by redis, directly push the data returned from redis to that WS channel

for example: if the WS client wants to subscribe to a channel called Binance:BTC-USDT:1m, and that data is coming from redis every minute, how do I send it to the WS client as soon as I get new data from Redis?

What would be the most efficient way to implement this?

```
export {};
const redis = require("redis");
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const subscriber = redis.createClient();
subscriber.psubscribe("*:*:*");
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

subscriber.on("pmessage", function (pattern, channel, message) {
  console.log(message);
});

wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
  ws.on("message", function incoming(message) {
    console.log("Server Received: %s", message);
  });

  ws.send("something from server");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ws.ts

```
import { IWSClient } from "./types/IChannel";

export default class WSHandler {
  sockets: Object = {};

  bindChannelWS(channel: any, client: IWSClient) {
    if (this.sockets[channel] === undefined) {
      this.sockets[channel] = [client];
    } else {
      this.sockets[channel].push(client);
    }
  }

  publishToChannel(channel: string, message: string) {
    if (this.sockets[channel] !== undefined) {
      this.sockets[channel].forEach(function (client: IWSClient) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(message));
        client.send(message);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
export {};
const redis = require("redis");
const WebSocket = require("ws");
import { IWSClient } from "./types/IChannel";
import WSHandler from "./ws";

const subscriber = redis.createClient();
subscriber.psubscribe("*:*:*");
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

var wsHandler = new WSHandler();

subscriber.on("pmessage", function (
  pattern: any,
  channel: string,
  message: string
) {
  wsHandler.publishToChannel(channel, message);
});

wss.on("connection", function connection(ws: IWSClient) {
  ws.on("message", function incoming(_subMessages: string) {
    let subMessages: Array<string> = JSON.parse(_subMessages);
    console.log("Server Received: ", subMessages);
    subMessages.forEach((channel) => wsHandler.bindChannelWS(channel, ws));
  });

  ws.send(JSON.stringify({ connection: "Initiated" }));
});
```